# Redirect child process output to parent's console using DataReceivedEventHandler

Tags: c#, process

I have a single host process that is responsible for spinning up multiple child processes. I want to print log messages from each child process to a file and also to the main console window for the host process.

The ProcessStartInfo is as follows for each child process:

```
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.ErrorDialog = false;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

I then set this for the child process:

```
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            File.AppendAllLines(filepath, new string[] { e.Data });
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        }
```

And finally start the process:

```
process.StartInfo = psi;
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

This works perfectly for writing the message to the logfile, but no matter what I try it won't output it in the console window. I've tried flushing the console as suggested elsewhere but it didn't help (Console.Out.Flush()).

Comment: If I step through the code, the console's title is correct but if I call Console.Clear() from the OutputDataReceived event, then I get an "invalid handle" error. So perhaps I need to strictly reference the console from the parent? I assumed it would bubble up.

Comment: If you get an exception from Console.Clear() then you don't have a console.  So you cannot see Console.Write() output either.  Somebody is going to have stop using CreateNoWindow = true, I guess.

Comment: Is the parent process exiting before the the child process? The process.Begin.. method are asynchronus and there for not blocking, so how are you keeping you parent process from completing? Are you using Process.WaitForExit()?

Comment: Correct, I'm using Process.WaitForExit. Note that the parent process still correctly logs info in the command window (for example, when I press 'enter' it shuts down all child processes and displays this information in the console).